# Only Dummy Output as sound device, after every wake-up from sleep

Tags: nvidia, sound, alsa, displayport, hda-intel

If I wake up my desktop computer (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) from sleep, the only sound device available is **DummyOutput**.

[image]

I followed advice on doing this:

```
$ pulseaudio -k ; alsa force-reload
```

...which fixes it:

[image]

But it only fixes it until the next time the system is woken from sleep. (Or maybe it is just a blanked screen as screensaver, not sure. I just wake it up from a blank screen.)

I followed additional advice on modifying `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` by adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

This makes it even worse: the DummyOutput is gone, and there is a `HDMI / DisplayPort - HDA NVidia` which does not work! Completely silent. Notice the **DisplayPort** in there, and not the **DisplayPort 3**.

```
$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: Workstation Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
...
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic 
...
```

Things that I tried, but did not help:

- **snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0** in grub configuration.
- **option snd-hda-intel dsp_driver=1** in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- **blacklist snd_soc_skl** in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Just be happy that you have a workaround, none works for me, pulseaudio dies when it goes to sleep, and only a reboot can restore the sinks, and that's it ; no one here has any solution.

Comment: You mean the problem went away, or the solution? Anyway, [I finally found something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631919/20393) : apparently pulseaudio is not the culprit, but the screen in which my HDMI cable is plugged, that sometimes forget to broadcast itself..?

Comment: @yPhil for me, the issue went away with upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10